# JQuery: How to AutoComplete "City, State"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Question**: How can you use the [JQuery Auto-Completion plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) to suggest a location (`"City, State"`) for an input field?

Meaning, someone wants to type in **"Chicago, IL"** ... so they begin typing `"Chi"` and it auto-suggestions `"Chicago, IL`".

*My biggest hurdles is finding a service that I can query to find out all US city+state names.*

I essentially want to do what the StackOverflow "Tags" input form works but form "City, State" auto completion.

Answer (score 40):

There's a group called GeoNames that offers both downloadable databases and free webservices to obtain this type of data.  For example, the search

```
http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?name_startsWith=Chic&country=US
```

will return a bunch of JSON that includes Chicago, IL (JSON properties include, among others, "name":"Chicago" and "adminCode1":"IL").

As it happens, the jQuery UI folks used this datasource for a [demo of autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp). (Thanks NickT for the link).

Comment: Very Cool, I found then the official integration at the link below --> http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Comment: @NickT You should accept this answer if you're still around. Recognize :-)

Comment: the demo link is broken, do you know of the new link please?

Comment: Anyway to integrate something like this into an Android EditText? Can we use jQuery for Android? I'm assuming now. @JacobMattison

Comment: There are a bunch of cities missing from the DB though :/

Answer (score 2):

You either need to make an ajax call to the server whenever a key is pressed to update the "auto complete" drop down, or include an array of all the possible "city-state" strings and filter them when a key is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

[@Teleport](https://teleport.org) offers an [API to search cities by name](https://developers.teleport.org/api/getting_started/#search_name), e.g.:
https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/?search=San,%20United%20States%20of%20America returns San Antonio, San Diego, San Jose and San Francisco. You can also pass state, e.g. https://api.teleport.org/api/cities/?search=San,%20Tex,%20United%20States%20of%20America only returns San Antonio. And you can also search by aiport codes (e.g. SFO) and other "aliases".

There's also an autocomplete widget for this API available at https://github.com/teleport/autocomplete

Disclosure: I work for Teleport.

EDIT: Added "of America" suffix in the "United States of America" search term, as some other countries (Brazil, Venezuela) have name forms that match "United States".

Comment: Hey, great API! Quick question though, is the autocomplete API really free? What If I want to use this for my site since I can't afford a google places api license?