# How to create three dependent input fields

Tags: jquery

How can I create three dependent input boxes with autocomplete function using jquery and php?

For example :

In the first input field I type in the name of the region and then in the second input field i can type in only citys from that region and then in third input field i can put streets only from that city.

Thanks

Comment: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586747/jquery-how-to-autocomplete-city-state) that might be helpful

Comment: Thanks. That can be helpful for autocomplete but how to make that these three input field depend on each other?

Comment: Here's how I would do it: When the user finishes the first input box, make a call to your server, and when the call comes back, populate the autocomplete of the second input box and enable it for user input, etc. I would recommend looking up tutorials to get your footing. At Stack Overflow we fix code, we don't write it, so good luck and if you run into any problems, come back and ask us a specific question about what you're hung up on!

Comment: Hi, i hoped that someone has an link for an good tutorial of something like that.

Comment: Here's [another question that might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890533/send-single-input-with-ajax-jquery-php). I'm afraid your question may be too broad to cover in a single tutorial, so you might need to break it into pieces (e.g. database, server-side code, client-side code).

Comment: Hi. Ok. Thanks for your help.